# Why does a photon carry out one-to-one interaction with an electron when 'QUANTUM SUPERPOSITION' exists?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, photoelectric-effect

I have read that only one-to-one interaction goes on between a photon and an electron, in the photoelectric effect.
But as I stumbled upon 'Hardy's Paradox', it gave a clear idea that to explain the paradox, quantum superposition needs to exist. And if this is the case, then the photon should be able to interact with more than one electron simultaneously. But that doesn't happen. Why this is so?

Comment: In the mainstream standard model of particle physics photons, and other elementary particles, are point particles and interact at fixed vertices with charged particles represented in quantum field theory by Feynman diagrams.  The theory accepts only three particle lines for each vertex.

Comment: Describing many-to-many interactions as sets of sequential one-to-one interactions (whether in a Feynman diagram or a verbal summary) is a crutch. There is definitely a finite cross section for two electrons with binding energy $E$ to be ionized by a photon of energy $2E$.

Comment: @ConnorBehan that would be a great answer I hope you post it